# How to insert text above the close tag of my xml file using sed (Jenkinsfile)?

Tags: xml, sed, jenkins-pipeline, xml-namespaces

I have changelog_master.xml as follows:

```
<databaseChangeLog xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog
   http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.4.xsd">

  <include file="changelog/version/changelog_1.0.xml"/>

</databaseChangeLog>
```

I would like to insert text above the close tag of my file like this

```
 <databaseChangeLog xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog
   http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.4.xsd">

  <include file="changelog/version/changelog_1.0.xml"/>
  <include file="changelog/version/changelog_1.1.xml"/>

</databaseChangeLog>
```

I have tried by using sed like this because I need to write it in Jenkinsfile for automation

```
sh "sed -i '/<\/databaseChangelog>/i <include file=\"changelog/version/changelog_${version}.xml\"/>' changelog/changelog_master.xml"
```

But it's not working. I have also tried many related questions.

What should I do now?

Thanks!

Comment: How is it "not working"? What are your results?

Comment: Obtained diff_Jenkinsfile from git git@gitlab.com:FINIZ-Repo/FINIZ-Liquibase.git

      org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
           WorkflowScript: 25: unexpected char: '\' @ line 25, column 19.
           sh "sed -i '/<\/databaseChangelog>/i <include file=\"changelog/version/changelog_${version}.xml\"/>' changelog/changelog_master.xml"

Comment: I suggest to use an XML/HTML parser (xmlstarlet, xmllint ...).

Comment: Can you give some examples?

Comment: Okay, see my answer.

Comment: I don't recommend the following: `sed 's|.*<include .*|&\n  <include file="changelog/version/changelog_1.1.xml"/>|' file.xml`

Comment: xmlstarlet looks easier. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a subnode and insert an attribute with`xmlstarlet` in an XML file with namespaces:

```
xmlstarlet edit \
  --omit-decl -N x="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog" \
  --subnode "//x:databaseChangeLog" -t elem -n "include" \
  --insert "//x:databaseChangeLog/include" -t attr -n "file" --value "changelog/version/changelog_1.1.xml" file.xml
```

Output to stdout:

```
<databaseChangeLog xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog    http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.4.xsd">
  <include file="changelog/version/changelog_1.0.xml"/>
  <include file="changelog/version/changelog_1.1.xml"/>
</databaseChangeLog>
```

---

If you want to edit file inplace, add option -L.

See: `xmlstarlet edit --help`

Answer (score 0):

sed also works, here is my version (you had typo in your matching template)

```
 $ sed -i "/<\/databaseChangeLog>/i\<include file=\"changelog/version/changelog_${version}.xml\"/>" changelog/changelog_master.xml
```